# Creating dynamic gradient from a grayscale color

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, gradient

I'm trying to generate a gradient for grayscale colors with the help of [color.js](https://github.com/brehaut/color-js?.utm_source=cdnjs&utm_medium=cdnjs_link&utm_campaign=cdnjs_library) library. The code below grabs the CSS variable `--color` and generates different tones by using the `devalueByAmount()` method. The gradient is successfully generated, however if possible I need help to generate smoother gradients.

Currently, the colors at the starting and ending points of the gradient seems too obvious. I'd like to smudge them out for smoother transition. Any ideas how I could achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
const Color = net.brehaut.Color;
const dropBy = 0.2;

let numOfTones = 500;
let color = Color(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--color'));

let scheme = [...Array(numOfTones).keys()].map((i, _, a) => {
  let drop = ((dropBy / numOfTones) * (i+1)).toFixed(3);
  let tone = (i != 0) ? color.devalueByAmount(drop) : color;
  return tone;
});

let grad = [...Array(numOfTones * 2).keys()].map((i, _, a) => {
  let numOfSteps = a.length - 2;
  let breakPoint = (((100 / 2) / (numOfSteps)) * (i-1)).toFixed(6);
  let colorNo = (i > numOfTones) ? numOfTones - (i - numOfTones) : i;
  let delimiter = i == (a.length - 1) ? ')' : ',';

  let s = `${(i < 1) ? `repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,` : `${scheme[colorNo - 1]} ${breakPoint}%${delimiter}`}`;

  return s;
}).join(' ');

root.style.setProperty('--grad', grad);
document.querySelector('div').classList.add('animate');
```

```css
:root {
  --color: #545454;
}
html {
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.animate {
  background: var(--grad);
  background-position: 400% 50%;
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient-animation 35s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes gradient-animation {
  0% { background-position: 400% 50% }
  100% { background-position: 0% 50% }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-js/1.0.1/color.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a [timing function](https://easings.net/#easeInOutSine) to control the drop value. Don't know why I didn't think of this before, but thank you anyway.

```
-(Math.cos(Math.PI * x) - 1)
```

It now generates wider end points.

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
const Color = net.brehaut.Color;
const dropBy = 0.2;

let numOfTones = 500;

let color = Color(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--color'));

let incrementer = 0;
let scheme = [...Array(numOfTones).keys()].map((i, _, a) => {
  incrementer += 1 / numOfTones;
  let drop = dropBy * -(Math.cos(Math.PI * incrementer) - 1) / 2;
  let tone = (i != 0) ? color.devalueByAmount(drop) : color;
  return tone;
});

let grad = [...Array(numOfTones * 2).keys()].map((i, _, a) => {
  let numOfSteps = a.length - 2;
  let breakPoint = (((100 / 2) / (numOfSteps)) * (i-1)).toFixed(6);
  let colorNo = (i > numOfTones) ? numOfTones - (i - numOfTones) : i;
  let delimiter = i == (a.length - 1) ? ')' : ',';

  let s = `${(i < 1) ? `repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,` : `${scheme[colorNo - 1]} ${breakPoint}%${delimiter}`}`;

  return s;
}).join(' ');

root.style.setProperty('--grad', grad);
document.querySelector('div').classList.add('animate');
```

```css
:root {
  --color: #545454;
}
html {
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.animate {
  background: var(--grad);
  background-position: 400% 50%;
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient-animation 35s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes gradient-animation {
  0% { background-position: 400% 50% }
  100% { background-position: 0% 50% }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-js/1.0.1/color.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```